# Why is this binary search tree an example of pre-order?

Tags: binary-search-tree, preorder

I'm a bit confused. I'm trying to learn about binary search tree's at the moment, and my understanding is that, in pre-order traversing, the left branch node value should be *less* than the root value. E.g., root: 7, leftchild: 6, rightchild: 8.

But I've seen this example of pre-order traversal that goes: 1 2 4 5 3. And images re-iterate that 1 is the root, and 2 is the leftchild node. But 2 is obviously more than 1.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Are you confusing a label in a diagram, written for the sake of explanation, with data actually contained in the node?  Such labels will typically be written left-to-right top-to-bottom.

Comment: No, this is a from an expected code output. Here is an image that shows what I'm talking about: https://i0.wp.com/algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/files/2015/11/Tree-Traversals.png

Comment: The reason is these types of traversals (pre-, in-, post-order, ...etc) are also a thing for binary trees that are *not* binary *search* trees. And most of them even have sense for trees that are not necessarily *binary*. The image you shared in comments does not claim the tree is a binary search tree.

Comment: That the left branch node value should be less than the root value is a condition for binary search trees, and is not related to the way we traverse the tree. The type of tree and the type of traversal are two largely distinct concepts.

Comment: @paparonnie  On the contrary, having seen the diagram, I am pretty sure the numbers in that diagram merely label the nodes.  If you interpret them as data, the tree is not a binary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of binary search trees is correct.

But pre-order traversals (and other types of traversals) are not just a thing for binary search trees. You will find examples of such traversals of other types of trees that are not necessarily binary search trees. Preorder, postorder, breadth-first and depth-first traversals are also relevant for any other kind of tree -- they don't have to be *search* trees, and not even *binary*.

Only inorder traversals assume the tree is binary. And if that inorder traversal happens to visit the tree values in their proper order, then we are dealing with a binary *search* tree.